# How to use short-cut paths to Compress-Archive to zip current folder into same destination

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am using `Compress-Archive` and want to zip the current directory into the same path. However I do not want to have to type out the entire file path both times. Is there an easy way to do this?

I am using windows 10 pro.

This works for the most part `Compress-Archive . test.zip` but I want it to be on the same level as the current directory so I need to put it back one spot.

Something like this is what I want:

```
path/test
path/test.zip
```

What I am getting:

```
path/test
path/test/test.zip
```

It is going inside the actual folder which is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably want that:

```
Compress-Archive * ..\test.zip
```

The wildcard `*` avoids that the name of the folder is put inside the zip.
Using `..` for the output path we go one level up in the directory tree.

This command will fail if `test.zip` already exists. Either add parameter `-update` to update the archive or add `-force` to overwrite the archive. Both can be used even if the archive does not already exist.

Comment: Try running the same command again after t.zip already exists in the directory.

Comment: @lit Thanks, I have improved the answer accordingly.

Comment: @zett42 - My understanding of the OP's question is that he wants the .zip file created in the current directory. Wouldn't this put the .zip file in the parent directory?

Comment: @lit That's what I thought at first, but he has updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the current working directory is "t", it can be included using the following command. I would note that I do not think putting the destination .zip file in the directory being compressed is a good idea.

```
Compress-Archive -Path $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude t.zip) -DestinationPath .\t.zip -Force
```

It is shorter if you are willing to use aliases and cryptic switches.

```
Compress-Archive $(gci -r -e t.zip) .\t.zip -Force
```

If I have misinterpreted your situation, please leave a comment or improve the information provided by editing the question.